# HTML/JS: Use anchor as default

Tags: javascript, html

In the www, you can use `someplace#position` to jump to the `#position` anchor withing the `someplace` html page.

I want to always jump to the `#position` anchor, if no anchor is specified. The reason is that I don't have control over all sites that link to `someplace`, therefore I cannot add the `#position` to the URLs everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Say this is your anchor:

`<a class="someplace" href="#someplace">someplace</a>`

Create a click event on page load:

`$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.someplace').click();
});`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is simply:

```
var curHash = document.location.hash;
document.location.hash = curHash === '#' || 'undefined' === typeof curHash ? 'position' : curHash.substring(1);
```

But it's worth noting that named anchors are somewhat obsolete, and replaced, in all browsers, by use of the `id`, therefore rather than:

```
<a name="position"></a>
<div>The 'position' area</div>
```

You'd have, instead:

```
<div id="position">The 'position' area</div>
```

References:

- [`Document.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.location).
- [`Location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location).
- [`URLUtils.hash`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLUtils.hash).

Comment: Hmm, I cannot get it to work: In Firefox, a "#" (without further name) is appended to the URL and it jumps to a different position (where no anchor exists). In Chrome, no # is appended, but it also jumps to the wrong location. In both browsers the correct location is not on top but in the middle of the page (maybe that is intentional?) Is your answer supposed to work with named anchors or div-ids or both?

Comment: The wrong location seems to be a symptom of the browsers trying to be smart and show the same view as before.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm wrong, but I think this will work:

```
window.location.hash = "#position"
```

Answer (score -1):

From what I understood is that you want to know whenever there is not 'hash' on the url ?

```
if(!window.location.hash.length)
{
    // No hash on the url, your code here ?
}
```